# pagination not working with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

table name - news

I create pagination code

here I am passing city and state from Navigation bar.
And on basis of that i Tried to show Row with pagination pages.

It works but on 2,3,4,5...N pages it shows error.

**Simply Pagination Not fetching data with where condition.**
plz suggest proper solution.

**when page loads it gets url like**

**localhost/hindi/city.php?state=19&city=16**

and display pagination rows below.

**But when i click on page2 it show url like**

**localhost/hindi/city.php?page=2**

and shows

**error**

**Undefined index: city**

**Undefined index: state**

Navigation code

```
<li><a href='city.php?state=20&city=18'>Bhopal</a></li>
  <li><a href='city.php?state=20&city=19'>Indore</a></li>
```

and other php code with pagination code

```
<?php 
require_once('includes/config.php');
$Admin = new admins;
$baseString = "detail.php";
$cit = $_REQUEST['city'];
$sta = $_REQUEST['state'];
?>

<?php           
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
$limit = 1;
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
$statement = "news";
?>
<?php
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$sql="select id,story,headline,photo from {$statement} where state_id = '$sta' and city_id = '$cit' order by id desc LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

//code to display pages

```
<?php echo $Admin->pagination($statement,$limit,$page); ?>
```

pagination function

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?')
        {        
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        //print_r($query);
        //exit;
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                    $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
        }


        return $pagination;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Show us the code where you generate links for page 2,3,4.. n.

Comment: sir i paste my code to echo pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

1. You need to pass full url (with all parameters except $page) in your Pagination method

   pagination($statement,$limit,$page,'city.php?state=20&city=18'); ?>

Then add $page parameter in your pagination method. It could be a bit tricky to determine whether to use "&" or not based on your current parameter.

2. You can add a new parameter in your pagination method to identify the current url parameters. You can then use them to generate full urls for pagination.

   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?', $parameters=array()){}

and pass the current url parameters ($city, $state) as an array when calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

In url `localhost/hindi/city.php?page=2` there is no `city` variable so `$_REQUEST['city']` is not define.
It's the same thing for `state` variable.

Comment: look at my url i passed state and city id from nav bar and on based of state and city id i need to display pages in pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if there are no page then 
let
page=1
limit=1
now startpoint=(1*1)-1=0 //correct

if you use 

page=2
then
SP=(2*1)-1=1 // one is start point and one is limit ?

i think its correct 

show me error message.. PLZ
```

Comment: error Undefined index: city and Undefined index: state .. i now why this error comes...bcoz when i click on page2 the condition in where clause goes blank....

Comment: undefiend index are not a programming error
if comes because you not pass any request city in url
for ignore you can use error_reporting(0);

or use

if(isset($_REQUEST['city'])){

Answer (score 0):

```
in method pagination($statement,$limit,$page) 
you pass only 3 variable but in method required constant 4 variable

for optionaly variable use 

example

function($var=null,$var2=null){
/*....your program....*/
}
now you can call
function();
function($arg1);
function($arg1,$arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

You have to pass city and state params to the pagination function.

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10, $page = 1, $params = array()) {
    ...
    $params['page'] = $page; // or $counter or $nextPage, ...
    ...
    $url = http_build_query($params);
    $html = '<a href="' . $url . '">XXX</a>';
}
```

Then, you call it passing the $_REQUEST (or another variable if you are generating params from other side);

```
$Admin->pagination($statement,$limit, $page, $_REQUEST);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
undefiend index are not a programming error
if comes because you not pass any request city in url
for ignore you can use error_reporting(0);

or use

if(isset($_REQUEST['city'])){
$city=$_REQUEST['city'];
}
else{
//....
//$city="default value";
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['state'])){
$state=$_REQUEST['state'];
}
else{
//default operation
}
```